# SSRS - Visual Studio

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hi I am a newbie Learning SSRS
While using concatenate function in expression i am getting an error

```
=(Fields!Bathroom.Value, "PropertyDetails") & " " & "Bathroom" & " " & (Fields!Bedroom.Value, "PropertyDetails") & "Bedroom"
```

Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where this expression is being used, it appears you need to adjust how you are declaring your fields.

If this is being used in a matrix or table with an explicit dataset assigned, you don't need to specify the dataset.

```
=Fields!Bathroom.Value & " Bathroom " & Fields!Bedroom.Value & " Bedroom"
```

If this is being used in a textbox, you'll need to specify some function to use with it, such as the `First` function, which will give the first item from that column.

```
=First(Fields!Bathroom.Value, "PropertyDetails") & " Bathroom " & First(Fields!Bedroom.Value, "PropertyDetails") & " Bedroom"
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for helping me, I was using in textbox, My problem is solve.